# How to get laser points in a specific time of a bag

Tags: ros, laser, scan, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some code that get the messages and break after there is something inside, but laser ranges data change every time I execute my code. This happens probably cause I get the msg in different periodo of time. I want set a specific time to get it, I mean get the ranges always at the same time.

This how I'm doing now.

```
while(ros::ok()) {
    for (i = 0; i < 540; i++) {
      if (!clustersScan.laserMsg.ranges.empty()) {
        RANGES[i] = clustersScan.laserMsg.ranges[i];
      }
    }

    if(!clustersScan.laserMsg.ranges.empty()) break;

    ros::spinOnce();
  }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256137/how-to-get-laser-points-in-a-specific-time-of-a-bag/) by [tiagoantunes14@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/27388/tiagoantunes14@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a lot missing from your code (how are you getting messages? is there a subscriber? why do you want a specific timestamp? how are you reading the bag file?) , so the best I can do is a generic answer:

rosbag has a [C++ API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) that can be used to read all of the messages from a bag file, in order. You can use this to get the first (or Nth) message from a bag file, or you can compare the header timestamps if you want a message with a specific timestamp.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tiagoantunes14@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/27388/tiagoantunes14@gmail.com/) on 2017-03-04**:
Generic answer was enough! Thanks!